# DNN7 issue with localized page URLs

Tags: localization, dotnetnuke, ddrmenu

I've just localized my DNN website into 3 languages, and for the default language I've set up custom Page URLs for most of the pages in the Page Settings field. I've tried to set this up the same for the other languages, but the menu isn't using the page urls I've set up, instead using the default URL for the page.

What I'm after is site.com/de/page-name. What I'm getting is site.com/de/Parent-Page/Child-Page. The url site.com/de/page-name loads fine when I access it directly.

Is there another setting somewhere to force the menu to use what's in the Page URL field?

I'm using DNN 7.1.2 with DDRMenu.

Comment: Please add some code so we can see what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: There isn't any code in particular that I'm using. It's using just the detault settings in DNN7 with Advanced URL management enabled. I haven't modified any code related to the menu or URLs. The default language version works completely fine, which suggests that all the code is working. But when I change languages, the menu isn't using the value in the Page URL field of the page settings.

Comment: I would imagine that this is a bug/limitation of the DDRMenu, though it could be something that might just need to be tweaked in the settings for DDRMenu (within the skin). You might try another skin that doesn't use DDRMenu (search for MultiFunction in the forge and you'll find my OpenSource skin). See if you experience the same results. It also might simply be a language bug in DNN